# How to reference column alias in cross apply

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to know how to reference my column alias in which the column is created via a SELECT.  I need to then reference that alias in my cross apply.  I wish not to repeat the SELECT in the cross apply because it would be very taxing on the database.

```
SELECT (SELECT CASE
                    WHEN Ord.OS_Thick_value = 'VAR'
                     AND PLANC.Cut_Thick_value <> '' THEN PLANC.Cut_Thick_value
                    ELSE Ord.OS_Thick_value
               END AS OS_Thick_value2) AS OS_Thick_value2,
       OS_Thick_value_Sort
FROM ORDERS Ord
     LEFT OUTER JOIN PLANC ON (Ord.Work_Order = PLANC.Work_Order
                           AND PLANC.Plan_Step = (SELECT MAX(Plan_Step)
                                                  FROM PLANC PcutDet
                                                  WHERE Ord.Work_Order = PcutDet.Work_Order)
                           AND PLANC.Plan_Cut = 1)
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE
                              WHEN ISNUMERIC(OS_Thick_value) = 1 THEN CAST(OS_Thick_value AS float)
                              WHEN OS_Thick_value = 'VAR' THEN CAST(1111 AS float)
                              WHEN OS_Thick_value = 'COIL' THEN CAST(1110 AS float)
                              WHEN CHARINDEX('-', OS_Thick_value) > 0
                               AND CHARINDEX('/', OS_Thick_value) > 0
                               AND CAST(LEFT(OS_Thick_value, CHARINDEX('-', OS_Thick_value, 1) - 1) AS float) > 0
                               AND CAST(SUBSTRING(OS_Thick_value, CHARINDEX('-', OS_Thick_value, 1) + 1, CHARINDEX('/', OS_Thick_value, 1) - CHARINDEX('-', OS_Thick_value, 1) - 1) AS float) > 0
                               AND CAST(RIGHT(OS_Thick_value, LEN(OS_Thick_value) - CHARINDEX('/', OS_Thick_value, 1)) AS float) > 0 THEN CAST(LEFT(OS_Thick_value, CHARINDEX('-', OS_Thick_value, 1) - 1) AS float) + (CAST(SUBSTRING(OS_Thick_value, CHARINDEX('-', OS_Thick_value, 1) + 1, CHARINDEX('/', OS_Thick_value, 1) - CHARINDEX('-', OS_Thick_value, 1) - 1) AS float) / CAST(RIGHT(OS_Thick_value, LEN(OS_Thick_value) - CHARINDEX('/', OS_Thick_value, 1)) AS float))
                              WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', OS_Thick_value) > 0
                               AND CHARINDEX('/', OS_Thick_value) > 0
                               AND CAST(LEFT(OS_Thick_value, CHARINDEX(' ', OS_Thick_value, 1) - 1) AS float) > 0
                               AND CAST(SUBSTRING(OS_Thick_value, CHARINDEX(' ', OS_Thick_value, 1) + 1, CHARINDEX('/', OS_Thick_value, 1) - CHARINDEX(' ', OS_Thick_value, 1) - 1) AS float) > 0
                               AND CAST(RIGHT(OS_Thick_value, LEN(OS_Thick_value) - CHARINDEX('/', OS_Thick_value, 1)) AS float) > 0 THEN CAST(LEFT(OS_Thick_value, CHARINDEX(' ', OS_Thick_value, 1) - 1) AS float) + (CAST(SUBSTRING(OS_Thick_value, CHARINDEX(' ', OS_Thick_value, 1) + 1, CHARINDEX('/', OS_Thick_value, 1) - CHARINDEX(' ', OS_Thick_value, 1) - 1) AS float) / CAST(RIGHT(OS_Thick_value, LEN(OS_Thick_value) - CHARINDEX('/', OS_Thick_value, 1)) AS float))
                              WHEN CHARINDEX('/', OS_Thick_value) > 0
                               AND CAST(LEFT(OS_Thick_value, CHARINDEX('/', OS_Thick_value, 1) - 1) AS float) > 0
                               AND CAST(RIGHT(OS_Thick_value, LEN(OS_Thick_value) - CHARINDEX('/', OS_Thick_value, 1)) AS float) > 0 THEN CAST(LEFT(OS_Thick_value, CHARINDEX('/', OS_Thick_value, 1) - 1) AS float) / CAST(RIGHT(OS_Thick_value, LEN(OS_Thick_value) - CHARINDEX('/', OS_Thick_value, 1)) AS float)
                              ELSE CAST(0 AS float)
                         END AS OS_Thick_value_Sort) OS_Thick_value_Sort
ORDER BY OS_Thick_value2 DESC;
```

Desired result:
I need to be able to reference "OS_Thick_value2" in my cross apply.

Comment: White space and line breaks are wonderful things... That statement is honestly an unreadable mess.

Comment: Also, I recommend against `ISNUMERIC`, it can (and does) return incorrect values; such as `ISNUMERIC(.)` returning `1`, and `ISNUMERIC('')` returning `0`. If you need to check if a value can be converted, use `TRY_CAST` or `TRY_CONVERT`; which is available in every **supported** version of SQL Server (which I assume you have, considering you haven't mentioned you're using unsupported software).

Comment: Even with SQL Prompt it's still a mess with those huge expressions; but it's better than it was. This smells more like an XY problem. What are you actually trying to achieve here. perhaps you could provide sample data and expected results, as the above seems to be far too overly complex.

Comment: Also, to answer your question, you can't reference a column in the `SELECT` by it's alias anywhere other than in the `ORDER BY` of that `SELECT`, or it an outer query. You certainly won't be able to reference `OS_Thick_value2` in the a subquery defined in the `FROM`.

Comment: Thank you.  Actually the Cross apply works as is.  But thank you for the suggestions on SYNTAX.

The TSQL looked all nice in SSMS, then when I copied it to this it came out like you see it.  


The idea behind OS_Thick_value2 is this: If my ORDER value is VAR then I want to get a numeric value from another table and field.  Which that part is working as desired.

But then within my cross apply it doesnt see the "numeric" value only the VAR from the ORDER table.  Id like the cross apply to interrogate my OS_Thick_value2 values

Comment: @MrAvgProgrammer . . . Surely you could simplify the code in the question to highlight the problem you are having.

Comment: Actually I cant.  Sure the cross apply is intense...but the issue doesn't reside in it directly.  Simply, I would like to be able to reference "OS_Thick_value2" in the Cross Apply.  OS_Thick_value2 is a Alias.

Comment: So far the best approach I have found is to repeat my (SELECT CASE
                    WHEN Ord.OS_Thick_value = 'VAR'
                     AND PLANC.Cut_Thick_value <> '' THEN PLANC.Cut_Thick_value
                    ELSE Ord.OS_Thick_value
               END AS OS_Thick_value2)

This isnt ideal, but it does work.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially How to [Ask], and read the [tsql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tsql/info) for instructions on how to create a [mcve] and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use aliases from the `select` clause in the `order by` clause, or in an outer query.
This is because the `apply` clause is logically processed by the SQL engine before the `select` clause is processed, as documented in the [Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement) paragraph of the SELECT (Transact-SQL) page:

> The following steps show the logical processing order, or binding order, for a SELECT statement. This order determines when the objects defined in one step are made available to the clauses in subsequent steps. [...] **because the SELECT clause is step 8, any column aliases or derived columns defined in that clause cannot be referenced by preceding clauses.** However, they can be referenced by subsequent clauses such as the ORDER BY clause. The actual physical execution of the statement is determined by the query processor and the order may vary from this list.
>
> 1. FROM
> 2. ON
> 3. JOIN
> 4. WHERE
> 5. GROUP BY
> 6. WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
> 7. HAVING
> 8. SELECT
> 9. DISTINCT
> 10. ORDER BY
> 11. TOP

(emphasis mine)

Since the `Apply` is considered as a part of the `FROM` (or `JOIN`) clause, it doesn't have access to the aliases defined in the `select` clause.

What you can do, however, is to move the computation of `OS_Thick_value2` into another `cross apply`, and then you can access it from your original `cross apply` clause:

```
SELECT OS_Thick_value2,
       OS_Thick_value_Sort
FROM ORDERS Ord
     LEFT OUTER JOIN PLANC ON (Ord.Work_Order = PLANC.Work_Order
                           AND PLANC.Plan_Step = (SELECT MAX(Plan_Step)
                                                  FROM PLANC PcutDet
                                                  WHERE Ord.Work_Order = PcutDet.Work_Order)
                           AND PLANC.Plan_Cut = 1)
    CROSS APPLY 
    (
        SELECT  CASE 
                    WHEN Ord.OS_Thick_value = 'VAR'
                        AND PLANC.Cut_Thick_value <> '' THEN PLANC.Cut_Thick_value
                    ELSE Ord.OS_Thick_value
                END AS OS_Thick_value2 -- This alias is accessible in the next cross apply clause.
    ) AS OS_Thick_value2 
    CROSS APPLY 
    (
        SELECT  CASE
                    WHEN ISNUMERIC(OS_Thick_value) = 1 THEN CAST(OS_Thick_value AS float)
                    WHEN OS_Thick_value = 'VAR' THEN CAST(1111 AS float)
                    WHEN OS_Thick_value = 'COIL' THEN CAST(1110 AS float)
                    WHEN CHARINDEX('-', OS_Thick_value) > 0
                        AND CHARINDEX('/', OS_Thick_value) > 0
                        AND CAST(LEFT(OS_Thick_value, CHARINDEX('-', OS_Thick_value, 1) - 1) AS float) > 0
                        AND CAST(SUBSTRING(OS_Thick_value, CHARINDEX('-', OS_Thick_value, 1) + 1, CHARINDEX('/', OS_Thick_value, 1) - CHARINDEX('-', OS_Thick_value, 1) - 1) AS float) > 0
                        AND CAST(RIGHT(OS_Thick_value, LEN(OS_Thick_value) - CHARINDEX('/', OS_Thick_value, 1)) AS float) > 0 THEN CAST(LEFT(OS_Thick_value, CHARINDEX('-', OS_Thick_value, 1) - 1) AS float) + (CAST(SUBSTRING(OS_Thick_value, CHARINDEX('-', OS_Thick_value, 1) + 1, CHARINDEX('/', OS_Thick_value, 1) - CHARINDEX('-', OS_Thick_value, 1) - 1) AS float) / CAST(RIGHT(OS_Thick_value, LEN(OS_Thick_value) - CHARINDEX('/', OS_Thick_value, 1)) AS float))
                    WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', OS_Thick_value) > 0
                        AND CHARINDEX('/', OS_Thick_value) > 0
                        AND CAST(LEFT(OS_Thick_value, CHARINDEX(' ', OS_Thick_value, 1) - 1) AS float) > 0
                        AND CAST(SUBSTRING(OS_Thick_value, CHARINDEX(' ', OS_Thick_value, 1) + 1, CHARINDEX('/', OS_Thick_value, 1) - CHARINDEX(' ', OS_Thick_value, 1) - 1) AS float) > 0
                        AND CAST(RIGHT(OS_Thick_value, LEN(OS_Thick_value) - CHARINDEX('/', OS_Thick_value, 1)) AS float) > 0 THEN CAST(LEFT(OS_Thick_value, CHARINDEX(' ', OS_Thick_value, 1) - 1) AS float) + (CAST(SUBSTRING(OS_Thick_value, CHARINDEX(' ', OS_Thick_value, 1) + 1, CHARINDEX('/', OS_Thick_value, 1) - CHARINDEX(' ', OS_Thick_value, 1) - 1) AS float) / CAST(RIGHT(OS_Thick_value, LEN(OS_Thick_value) - CHARINDEX('/', OS_Thick_value, 1)) AS float))
                    WHEN CHARINDEX('/', OS_Thick_value) > 0
                        AND CAST(LEFT(OS_Thick_value, CHARINDEX('/', OS_Thick_value, 1) - 1) AS float) > 0
                        AND CAST(RIGHT(OS_Thick_value, LEN(OS_Thick_value) - CHARINDEX('/', OS_Thick_value, 1)) AS float) > 0 THEN CAST(LEFT(OS_Thick_value, CHARINDEX('/', OS_Thick_value, 1) - 1) AS float) / CAST(RIGHT(OS_Thick_value, LEN(OS_Thick_value) - CHARINDEX('/', OS_Thick_value, 1)) AS float)
                    ELSE CAST(0 AS float)
                END AS OS_Thick_value_Sort) OS_Thick_value_Sort
ORDER BY OS_Thick_value2 DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you. I am going to give that a try and see how it looks.